# GridView cell as hyperlink

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a hyperlink in a gridview cell which works fine, however in order to improve the experience of my users I would like the whole cell to be clickable rather than just the text as in most cases the text is a single digit.

e.g.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Qty">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HyperLink ID="Lnk" runat="server"
           NavigateUrl='<%# "View.aspx?ID=" + Eval("ID") %>'
           Text='<%# Eval("Qty") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

How can I make the entire table cell clickable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it using java-script

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Qty" ItemStyle-CssClass="clickable">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HyperLink ID="Lnk" runat="server"
           NavigateUrl='<%# "View.aspx?ID=" + Eval("ID") %>'
           Text='<%# Eval("Qty") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

if using jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.clickable').on('click', function(){
         window.location.href = $(this).children('a').attr('href');
    });
});
```

you can also decorate your cell with css like

```
.clickable { cursor: pointer; }
```